# Rails 5.2.3: Sidekiq Scheduler gives NameError: uninitialized constant in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5.2

In my Rails 5.2.3 app I have `config/sidekiq.yml` which looks like this:

```
:verbose: true
:concurrency: 30
:queues:
  - [mailers, 7]
  - [critical, 6]
  - [default, 5]
  - [low, 4]

:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log

:schedule:
  ScheduledNotices:
    queue: low
    cron: '0 0 * * * *' # every hour
```

My `ScheduledNotices` is placed in `lib\scheduled_notices.rb`

At the moment in development environment [Scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) works as expected, however in production I get this error: `NameError: uninitialized constant ScheduledNotices`

In my application.rb I have:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

**What am I doing wrong, please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be realated to path autoload issue, check this for more details: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142#issuecomment-275492070

What you should do is to change:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

to

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: Thank you, looks like this is the solution.